# Find the minimum of $|a+\frac 2 {a-1}|$ where $|a|\leq2$.

Tags: optimization, derivatives

> Find the minimum of $|a+\frac 2 {a-1}|$ where $|a|\leq2$.

I tried using differentiation, but the absolute makes things troublesome...

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the minimum of $a+\frac{2}{a-1}$ on the interval $(1,2]$, and the minimum of $-(a+\frac{2}{a-1})$ on the interval $[-2,1)$.  Take the smaller of these two minima and you're done.

These intervals were determined by checking when the inside of the absolute value was positive vs. negative.

Comment: How to find the minimum of $a+2/(a-1)$ on $(1,2]$? If I find it by solving $dy/dx=0$, how can I make sure that the minimum is not at the boundary such that $dy/dx\neq0$?

Comment: To check minima of $f(x)$ on the boundary of $(1,2]$, you take $f(2)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1+} f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x+\frac{2}{x-1}$.   Find where the derivative is $0$ in our interval, and evaluate $|f|$ at these and at the endpoints $\pm 2$. We will end up wanting to evaluate $|f|$ at $-2$, $1-\sqrt{2}$ and $2$.